# Ideas for a simple tic tac toe algorithm in assembly

Tags: algorithm, assembly, tic-tac-toe

I need to develop an algorithm for the machine to play vs a human in the Tic Tac Toe game.

The problem is that the game must be written in assembly for an ancient processor [(Motorola 6809)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6809). I have already developed the human vs human mode and now I only have to add a piece of code which makes a move vs the human.

I  have been purposed to do it so the bot plays either to win or just not to lose.

Well, I know that applying the Minimax algorithm would be perfect, but doing it in assembly would take a lot of days. So, has anyone an idea of how could I make it?
Would be easier playing to win or not to lose?

Remember that this processor cannot generate random numbers because there is no way to check the time or the amount of cycles done.

Comment: Does it have to be a perfect algorithm (i. e. from every position always picking the best move)? For an imperfect  one, just detect next-move-wins situations and move there. If none exist, move in the following order of availability: center, corner, side. The first move is always center.

Comment: No, it does not have to be perfect. That is the idea I have in mind. If there are not more answers I will start working at it.

Comment: Did you look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe#Strategy)?

Comment: Is there enough space for a 3^9 = 19683 byte table? If so, just encode the next move there.

Comment: Just bear in mind that if the computer **plays to win** and it starts, you will never win, and if you start you can only draw. There is not point in such a game.

Comment: In case you feel like hardcoding all the moves: https://xkcd.com/832/

Comment: @seva-alekseyev No, I did not mean that. Where can you find in my question "code it for me, please"? I just wanted to know if there was an easy way to decide the best movement in order to win or not to lose. I think it is quite good explained in the question. 

I have to add that I wrote all the code that afternoon on my own because I did not noticed Jester answer, which would have been very useful (thanks to you Jester, as well as the other people willing to help), and the bot is unbeatable.

I just do not understand the reason of this rude answer.